# Powershell Licensing Sub Plans

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the assigned licenses for a particular user but for some reason the list does not show the sub plans. Here's the powershell that I am using:

```
        *get-msoluser -userprincipalname abc@xyz.com | select licenses*
```

It is listing only the OFFICESUBSCRIPTION and ECAL_SERVICES which correct. The user also has ONEDRIVESTANDARD which is not showing up. I shall appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To view which services a user has access to, try running

```
(Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName <Account>).Licenses[<LicenseIndexNumber>].ServiceStatus
```

where `<Account>` is your UPN and `<LicenseIndexNumber>` is the index of the license you want to investigate.

When you run the cmdlet you should see something like:

```
ServicePlan                       ProvisioningStatus
-----------                       ------------------
SWAY                              Success
INTUNE_O365                       Success
YAMMER_ENTERPRISE                 PendingInput
RMS_S_ENTERPRISE                  Success
OFFICESUBSCRIPTION                Success
MCOSTANDARD                       Success
SHAREPOINTWAC                     Success
SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE              Success
EXCHANGE_S_ENTERPRISE             Success
```

where `Success` means the service is available and `Disabled` means exactly that. `PendingInput` means that Office 365 is still processing the service request.

Have a look at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771771.aspx. There's plenty of information on this topic and how to run the above cmdlet.